# Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row '0'

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My HTML code:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>
    <td>Links</td>
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">www.google.com</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').DataTable();
})
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/paczbj35/

When I run it I get a "Requested unknown parameter '1' from the data source for row '0'" error.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: The error message gives you a [link to follow for more information](http://datatables.net/tn/4). So what did you find there?

Comment: @squint - a whole lot of text whose applicability is not immediately obvious. Maybe I should turn what seems to me to be a easy enough question to read into a ten page essay that no one is going to read?

Comment: Or maybe you should just acknowledge the information link in your question and explain that you did indeed read it in full (if you did) and still couldn't figure out the issue. Then we wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: @neubert woa... pump the brakes. Don't think squint's intent was to be malicious. Those pages can be confusing, however, once you learn how to look at them they can explain a lot. The link says - `when DataTables tries to obtain data for a cell and is unable to do so, it will trigger a warning`. This immediately tells me that there was an issue obtaining the data, so it is having trouble reading in the data table. Why might it have an issue reading in the table? - could be because the table syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Could be because your table structure is syntactically incorrect. `<th>` is the equivalent of a `<td>` tag, just for `<thead>`, but it can be used as a cell anywhere in your table. You are using it as if `<th>` means a row for the table header.

Your error message is also telling you exactly where the issue is... row 0 column 1

Try -

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Links</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">www.google.com</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<th>` isn't just for the `<thead>`. It's useful in a `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` too.